# GlassFish cluster-targeted jdbc is not enabled

Tags: cluster, glassfish, jdbc

I have a GlassFish cluster.

When I tried to add node and a instance, DAS saids a bunch of error messages telling

```
Resource [ jdbc/xxxx ] of type [ jdbc ] is not enabled

[#|2012-11-14T12:07:04.318+0900|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=2803;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:318)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
        at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:480)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.flush(StreamHandler.java:242)
        at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:106)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:522)
        at com.sun.logging.LogDomains$1.log(LogDomains.java:372)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:543)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:607)
        at com.sun.enterprise.resource.deployer.JdbcResourceDeployer.deployResource(JdbcResourceDeployer.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceProxy.create(ResourceProxy.java:90)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:507)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ResourceNamingService.lookup(ResourceNamingService.java:221)
```

the JDBC Resource is ok and targeted with the cluster.

I've installed the JDBC driver on the new node.

Can anybody help?

----------------------------------------- ANSWER

I found that the JDBC/address has been wrongly set that only one node knows but unknown for others.

Comment: Please post your solution as answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering for my own question.

The `JDBC Connection Pool`'s `address` property was wrong.

It was a DNS name about which only one of three nodes knows.